# "How To Ask" text is wrong for Stack Exchange Meta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, stackexchange-2.0

At first I thought this was just an error on the Cooking site but it turns out it's like this on all SE metas.  If you go to the meta site and click "Ask Question", the sidebar that pops up says (for example):

> Is your question about the Personal Finance and Money Meta - Stack Exchange community or website?

I don't think that the word "Meta" should be in there.  I'm *on* the meta; I'm not there to *ask about* the meta.  The wording should probably be:

> Is your question about the Personal Finance and Money - Stack Exchange community or website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was completed a while ago, sorry about that.

https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

> #### How to Ask
>
> Is your question about the Cooking - Stack Exchange community or website?
>
> Provide details. Show examples.
>
> Whenever possible, link to the relevant questions, answers, users, or page on the site you''re discussing.
>
> [read the faq »](http://example.com)